# Fast way of finding a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

> Show that $D_{12}$, the dihedral group of order $12$, is isomorphic to the direct product $D_6\times C_2$.

I can do it by just checking that each element in one has an equivalent element in the other, but is there a quicker way of showing that there must exist an isomorphism?

Comment: Welcome to the Math.SE! Here is a tutorial on mathjax- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Mathjax is how we format our maths here, changing x^2 to $x^2$

Comment: The OP means for $D_{2n}$ to mean the dihedral group of order $2n$. I've edited this in, as the notation is notoriously ambiguous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, there are two answers, each depending on which notation you mean. Does $D_n$ mean the dihedral group of order $n$, or of order $2n$? My original answer assumed that the OP meant $D_n$ has order $n$, but in the comments it is apparent that they mean it has order $2n$. So I'll first answer the question they *meant*, and then I'll leave my original answer.

---

**Answer 1:** If $D_6$ has order $6$ then you can show that $D_{12}\cong D_6\times C_2$ as follows. The idea is to show that it is the *internal* direct product of $D_6$, the dihedral group of order $6$, and $C_2$, so $D_{12}=MN$ where $M\cap N=1$, and $M$ and $N$ are both normal in $D_{12}$.

Take $N$ to be the natural copy of $D_6$ in $D_{12}$: remember that $D_{12}$ is acting on a hexagon, and we can make this look like a triangle by rotating twice. So $D_6$ embeds by rotating twice. Take $M$ to be the half-twist. Clearly, $M\cong C_2$ and $M\cap N=1$. Finally, note that $M$ is central in $D_{12}$, which implies that both $M$ and $N$ are normal in $D_{12}$ (because $mn=nm$ for all $n\in N$ so $mnm^{-1}=m$, and normality follows as $D_{12}=MN$). This proves the result.

---

**Answer 2:** If $D_6$ has order $12$ then there doesn't exist an isomorphism.

The centre of a group $G$ is the set $\{g\in G\mid gx=xg \:\forall\: x\in G\}$. Isomorphism preserve the centre of a group (heck, they preserve everything! But centre's are what are relevant here). So,

**Hint:** The centre of $D_{2n}$, the dihedral group of $4n$ has order $2$. (The non-trivial element is the half-twist: it commutes with everything.)

Comment: Perhaps I asked the second part of my question wrong due to lack of understanding. I know for certain that $D_{12}$ is isomorphic to $D_6 \times C_2$ , but doesn't that mean there exists an isomorphism between them?

Comment: If $D_{12}$ denotes the dihedral group of order $12$ then, yes, you are correct, there is an isomorphism between $D_{12}$ and $D_6 \times C_2$. A possible source of confusion is that some people insist on using $D_n$ to denote the dihedral group of order $2n$, and I think that user1729 is using that alternative convention!

Comment: yes it is an annoying ambiguity that somehow persists. however every dihedral group whose order is divisible by four has a central involution (the 'half-twist') which permits the isomorphism with a direct product of $\mathbb{C_2}$ and the quotient dihedral group.

Comment: @DavidHolden I think this only works if the dihedral group is divisible by $4$ but not by $8$.

Comment: @Derek Yes, $4$ but not $8$. Otherwise the copy of $D_{n/2}$ does not intersect trivially with the half twist, so the extension does not split.

Comment: (Also, @ThanksABundle, I've edited my post to answer your question. Sorry for the misunderstanding!)